# Java project: error when running sbt compile

Tags: java, compilation, java-8, sbt

I have a java project that lacks any dependency management. Picked SBT to add dependency management and to build it.

I've add build.sbt, sbt.plugins in the project. When I try to compile the project I'm seeing this errors for classes that exist in src/main but are being accessed in src/test.

```
$ sbt compile
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from C:\web\web_automation\project
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to web_automation (in build file:/C:/web/web_automation/)
[info] Executing in batch mode. For better performance use sbt's shell
[info] Compiling 385 Java sources to C:\web\web_automation\target\classes ...
[error] C:\web\web_automation\src\main\java\com\Wait.java:4:1:  error: cannot find symbol
[error] import GlobalConfig;
[error]                                           ^^  symbol:   class GlobalConfig
```

Any idea what causes these errors?

build.sbt

```
// Project name (artifact name in Maven)
name := "web_automation"

// orgnization name (e.g., the package name of the project)
organization := ""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

// project description
description := "Selenium Automated tests for web."

// Enables publishing to maven repo
publishMavenStyle := false

// Do not append Scala versions to the generated artifacts
crossPaths := false

// This forbids including Scala related libraries into the dependency
autoScalaLibrary := false

// library dependencies. (orginization name) % (project name) % (version)
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math3" % "3.1.1",
  "org.fluentd" % "fluent-logger" % "0.2.10",
  "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % "3.6.0",
  "org.uncommons" % "reportng" % "1.1.4"
)

enablePlugins(TestNGPlugin)
```

Comment: The error is in a file in `src/main`. Where does that `GlobalConfig` import come from? Is it your code? Is it also in `src/main`?

Comment: its in src/test

Comment: Code in `src/main` cannot depend on the code in `src/test` (another way yes)